# View.OnTouchListener and screen rotation coordination

Tags: android, android-activity, ontouchlistener, android-lifecycle

I am writing an `Activity` that implements `View.OnTouchListener`. I noticed that if I press my finger to the screen, change the screen orientation (which triggers `Activity` destruction and recreation) while keeping my finger down, and then lift my finger, the `OnTouchListener.onTouch` doesn't get called. It seems like it should, since lifting my finger is a `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`. Am I misunderstanding the library/using it wrong, or is this a bug in the framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the rotation starts, your `onTouch` listener should receive a `MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL` completing the event stream. You don't receive an additional `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` because no new event stream has been started.

Comment: thanks Buch. so there's no way to get only the `ACTION_UP` in the new `Activity`?